# Observable retry / retryWhen with flatmap

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following code to get id and then data related to the id.

```
process(): Observable<any> {
    let id: number;
    return this.getId().flatMap(
        (response: number) => {
                id = response;
                return this.getData(id)
        }
    ).flatMap(
        (data: any) => {
            return Observable.of(data);
        }
    );
}

getData(id: number): Observable<any> {
    // retry if response.status is not complete
    return this.service.getData(id).map(response => return response.data); 
}
```

I would like to add retry logic on getData method until response.status is not complete. I tried adding retry/retryWhen after this.getData(id) but no luck. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`retry` and `retryWhen` are suitable for error handling, meaning that the source observable has to produce an error for these operators to make an effect. I guess that in your case you want to retry not on error, but on a status that you don't like.

Probably the simplest way to achieve that would be to make service calls on some interval and take the first response with the status you want:

```
getData(id) {
    return Observable.interval(100)
        // make 5 attempts to get the data
        .take(5)
        .concatMap(() => this.service.getData(id))
        .filter(response => response.status === "complete")
        .take(1)
        .map(response => response.data)
}
```

Now `getData()` returns an observable that either emits a single value that corresponds to a response with a "complete" status and then completes, *or completes without emitting any value after 5 unsuccessful attempts to get the data with the desired status (the answer updated in response to a comment)*.

**Update:**

It is, of course, possible to turn responses with "bad" statuses into errors and use the `retry` functionality, as you proposed:

```
getData(id) {
    return this.service.getData(id)
        .concatMap(response => response.status === "complete" ?
            Observable.of(response) :
            Observable.throw("Bad status"))
        .map(response => response.data)
        .retry(5);
}
```

If things go wrong, this code will try to fetch the data at most 6 times (1 initial + 5 retries) and then will produce an error that you would have to handle, for example with `catch` operator. One drawback is that this way does not distinguish "real" errors (e.g. network failures) from errors produced out of bad statuses, but this could be handled with `retryWhen`.

Comment: You are correct, retry and retryWhen are suitable for error handling. I would like to stop retry after x number of attempts,is it possible to include this condition in your code?

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to create an error result based on status to use retry and retryWhen?

Comment: Both ways are possible, I updated the initial solution (`.take(5)`) and added another one (`retry(5)`). Beware that you would need to handle a case when specified number of retries is not enough, e.g. by `.catch(() => Observable.empty())` or another way that suits your needs.

Comment: I have also replaced 'first(...)` with 'filter(...).take(1)' in the original solution to avoid an error that 'first()' produces in case if the source observable completes without emitting any value that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have tryed retry method and it works.

```
(Observable ...).retry(2).map(...).subscribe(...)
```

When I do a http call and the response is for example a 404 it retries the call twice.