# Angular 4.3 Observables: how to retry with an interval and max retries?

Tags: angular, observable

I am new to Angular 4.3.  I have a mapping application that renders a "map layer" by downloading a series of small images ("tiles"). At start-up, the map layer can take anywhere from 0.1 - 5.0 seconds to download.

I need to trigger an event when the client has received two or more tiles. I had thought I might achieve this by subscribing to an Observable that retries up to 30 times, on a 200ms interval.

So far:

```js
  public updateTileContainer() {
    this._getTileContainer().subscribe(container => {
      if (container) {
        console.log('* do stuff with container *');
      }
    });
  }

  private _getTileContainer(): Observable<any> {

    return Observable.interval(200)
      .mergeMap(function (n) {

        const tileImages = $('#mymap').find('img[src*=\'kml\']');

        console.log(`Retry ${n}: ${tileImages.length} tiles found`);

        if (!tileImages || tileImages.length < 2) {
          return Observable.of(null);
        }

        const tileContainer = getContainer(tileImages);

        return Observable.of(tileContainer);
      })
      .take(30);
  }
```

This works!  Sort of.  I get this output:

```
Retry 0: 0 tiles found
Retry 1: 0 tiles found
Retry 2: 0 tiles found
Retry 3: 0 tiles found
Retry 4: 0 tiles found
Retry 5: 0 tiles found
Retry 6: 0 tiles found
Retry 7: 2 tiles found
* do stuff with container *
Retry 8: 3 tiles found
* do stuff with container *
Retry 9: 9 tiles found
* do stuff with container *
Retry 10: 12 tiles found
* do stuff with container *
etc.
```

What I'm actually trying to do is emit a single event, at "Retry 7", and then stop emitting.

How can I change this to "complete" the Observable as soon as I've found the container?  And how can I "skip" emitting events for Retries 0 to 6, as they aren't really events?  And can I throw an error from the Observable if it gets to 30 retries without finding the container?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372730/483655) looks like it might shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `.retry(count)`

You can throw an error if there is less than 2 tiles inside your selection. and then `retry()` 30 times.

**NB:** after the 30th retry, the error will actually be emitted and you'll need to handle it. But this might be a good thing (see further).

```js
public updateTileContainer() {
  this._getTileContainer().subscribe(container => {
      console.log('* do stuff with container *');
  },error=>{
      console.log('no container found !');
  });
}

private _getTileContainer(): Observable <any> {
  return Observable.timer(200).map(()=>{
    const tileImages = $('#googlemap').find('img[src*=\'kml\']');
    if (tileImages.length <= 2)
      throw new Error("not enough tiles !");
    return getContainer(tileImages);
  })
  .retry(30);
}
```

Your solution and @JonStødle's do work. But note that you won't be notified if you cannot get any container. Indeed if the container is not found, the Observable just complete, no error.

If you want to know that your are not able to find the container, dealing with errors might be a good thing.

Comment: Ahh, so `retry(N)` suppresses those errors until the final retry?  And `console.log('no container found !');` will only be executed once?

Comment: Exactly., That's it.

Comment: I have not tested this myself, but it looks like something that can be useful. It made me understand observables better anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things in programming, there are multiple ways of achieving the same result - it mostly comes down to preference.

Here's my stab at a solution. Personally I find it more readable:

```js
private _getTileContainer(): Observable<any> {

return Observable.interval(200)
    .map(_ => $('#googlemap').find('img[src*=\'kml\']')) // 1
    .take(30) // 2
    .skipWhile(tiles = tiles.length < 2) // 3
    .map(tiles => getContainer(tiles)) // 4
    .take(1); // 5
}
```

1. Get the image tiles.
2. Ensure we don't do this more than 30 times.
3. Skip signal emitted until we have at least 2 tiles.
4. Get the container.
5. Only take 1 container.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me what I need, but I'm not sure if there's a better way

```js
public updateTileContainer() {
  this._getTileContainer().subscribe(container => {

      console.log('* do stuff with container *');

  });
}


private _getTileContainer(): Observable<any> {

  return Observable.interval(200)
    .concatMap(n => {
      let tileContainer: any = null;

      const tileImages = $('#googlemap').find('img[src*=\'kml\']');         
      if (tileImages.length >= 2) {
        tileContainer = getContainer(tileImages);
      }

      return Observable.of(tileContainer);
    })
    .take(30)
    .filter(res => res !== null)
    .take(1);
}
```

So following on from the original example, the main Observable emits `nulls` for the first 6 or 7 retries, but the `filter()` stops them from being passed on to the subscriber.  The `take(30)` stops the main Observable after 30 retries, whereas the `take(1)` after the `filter()` stops the Observable after the first *non-null* retry.

Answer (score 0):

> Works on rxjs version 6.3.3

```
    import { map, catchError, retryWhen, take, delay, concat } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { throwError } from 'rxjs';


export class ApiEXT {

    static get apiURL(): string { return 'http://localhost:57886/api'; };
    static httpCLIENT: HttpClient;

 static POST(postOBJ: any, retryCOUNT: number = 0, retryITNERVAL: number = 1000) {
        return this.httpCLIENT
            .post(this.apiURL, JSON.stringify(postOBJ))
            .pipe(
                map(this.handleSUCCESS),
                retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(retryITNERVAL), take(retryCOUNT), concat(throwError("Giving up Retry.!")))),
                catchError(this.handleERROR));
    }


  private static handleSUCCESS(json_response: string): any {
        //TODO: cast_and_return    
        return JSON.parse(json_response);

    }

 private static handleERROR(error: Response) {
        let errorMSG: string;
        switch (error.status) {
            case -1: errorMSG = "(" + error.status + "/" + error.statusText + ")" + " Server Not Reachable.!"; break;
            default: errorMSG = "(" + error.status + "/" + error.statusText + ")" + " Unknown Error while connecting with server.!"; break;
        }
        console.error(errorMSG);
        return throwError(errorMSG);
    }

}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-basics-8swzpy)